# Keep getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: asp.net

On our development environment system works fine but on Live system sometimes buttonClick action generates below error. If i press back 1-2 times it works without generating error.

On the live system error, it still shows my local path. Can this be the issue?
Thanks for your help

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.`

Exception Details:

`System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Source Error:

`An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.`

Stack Trace:

`[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   WebApplication4.orderConfirmation.SubmitButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\Purchase\WebApplication4\WebApplication4\orderConfirmation.aspx.cs:341
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +153
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3690`

Comment: Would you mind posting the code for `SubmitButton_Click` and also point out which line is line 341 in `orderConfirmation.aspx.cs`

Comment: Please ad details when you have narrow  down the error. With this few informations there are endless possible reasons.
Btw, you're local path is added because it was last compiled as debug on your local machine and you have copied this .pdb-file to the server, but that doesn't cause an exception .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer one question: when compiling .NET code into DLL, the local path of the source files is being stored in the assembly - not sure if only when compiling in Debug or also in Release.

Anyway, add the generated .PDB file to the same folder containing the DLL file on the server and you'll also get line number (instead of cryptic +3690): having this you can identify the exact line causing this error.. post this information here and we'll be able to help.

Comment: So probably it will show exact line only when the EXE is compiled under Debug mode. Try compiling in Debug mode and hopefully you'll have the line number..

Comment: @EnginBodur marking this as correct means you got line number and solved this by yourself or do you still need help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you might have the page life cycle wrong and you might be setting a variable at a certain point and expecting that variable not to be null when you are accessing it.